Springboot2 and custom refreshable resolver
I am working on a spring boot 2.7 service and trying to understand how to use custom placeholders like ${key} vs $%key% or similar. I am not stuck on using a custom placeholder, but I also need to resolve the values with a custom service.
So that @Value can be refreshed based on time or TTL with service or WebClient that has caching built in.
I have looked at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
but I am looking for a concrete example of how to implement it.

Spring Cloud already provides this with @RefreshScope.
